# How is Test MSE being calculated here?

Tags: machine-learning, mse

I'm reading Andrew Ng's CS229 course notes on machine learning, and I'm at the part about [Bias-Variance Tradeoff](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes5.pdf). Here, we're modeling our data as $y_i = f(x_i) + \epsilon_i$ where $\epsilon_i$ are i.i.d. with $\mathbb{E}[\epsilon_i]=0$ and $\text{Var}[\epsilon_i] = \sigma^2$. We learn a model $\hat{f}$ based off the training samples (and so this $\hat{f}(x)$ is actually a random variable for all $x$ in our test set).

Now, they go on to calculate the Test MSE as follows:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{Test MSE} & = \mathbb{E}\left((y-\hat{f}(x))^2\right) \\
& = \mathbb{E}\left((\epsilon + f(x) - \hat{f}(x))^2\right) \\
& = \mathbb{E}\left(\epsilon^2\right) + \mathbb{E}\left((f(x) - \hat{f}(x))^2\right) \\
& = \sigma^2 + \left(\mathbb{E}(f(x) - \hat{f}(x))\right)^2 + \text{Var}(f(x) - \hat{f}(x)) \\
& = \sigma^2 + \left(\text{Bias}(\hat{f})\right)^2 + \text{Var}(\hat{f})
\end{aligned}
$$
I don't really have any problem with the formulas above, I can go from one to the next. What I don't understand is what the expectation is being taken over in the first place. What exactly does $\mathbb{E}((y - \hat{f}(x))^2)$ mean?

My intuition is telling me it's being taken over the training set $(x, y)\in\text{Test Set}$, with samples being drawn uniformly, but this doesn't make a lot of sense to me because I thought the whole point is that $\hat{f}$ is a random variable over the *samples* $\epsilon_i$, so shouldn't the expectation be over the $\epsilon_i$'s? If so, then are $x$ and $y$ just an arbitrary sample from the test set? How is $\text{Var}(\epsilon) = \sigma^2$, is $\epsilon$ our random variable here?

I'm just so confused about how *exactly* each of these expectations is being calculated. I get the gist of it, and I have no problem with formulas involving the expectation (like the fact that $\mathbb{E}[\epsilon^2] = \text{Var}(\epsilon) + \mathbb{E}[\epsilon]^2 = \text{Var}(\epsilon)$), I just don't understand what these expectations are being taken with respect to.

Comment: f(x) is the prediction of your model. If the model perfectly predicts y, then y-f(x) is zero, and that is the loss function being minimized here. When averaging this squared error over samples in the training/test set, you have a cost function called the mean squared error. Is all of this clear?

Comment: @hirschme Yes I suppose, so you're saying the expectation is averaged over pairs $(x, y)$ in the training set? What exactly is $\epsilon$ then?

Comment: Because you are modeling y to be equal to f(x) plus some additional noise $\epsilon$, then the best your model can perform is that error term, as it can't be predicted.

Comment: @hirschme Yes, that makes sense, but that doesn't help me understand the precise meaning of the formulas above unfortunately. I can talk about Test MSE and the model learning in English confidently, but I can't really prove much about the formulas without knowing what they precisely correspond to (in English).

Comment: If you now understand why we choose the term $\mathbb{E}((y - \hat{f}(x))^2)$ to describe the performance of a model $f(x)$ on data $(x,y)$ (regardles if it is training or test), then the rest is just algebra. In this case, the stochastic noise term $\epsilon$ is chosen to be standard gaussian noise, which has characteristics $\mathbb{E}(\epsilon) = 0$ and $Var(\epsilon) = \sigma^2$ ($\epsilon$ ~ $N(0, \sigma^2)$)

Comment: @hirschme I understand why $\mathbb{E}((y - \hat{f}(x))^2)$ makes sense to describe $f$ on data. What I don't understand is how this corresponds to the usual formula I've learned, which is $\mathbb{E}(X) = \sum_x x p(x)$.

Comment: The expected value of a distribution can be computed like you say if we know the true underlying probability function $p(x)$. Whenever we don't know that, we use the 'average' value, weighting the samples by their frequency instead of the probability, which is the same as the mean value. The expected value here corresponds to the mean value across N sampled pairs $(x_i,y_i)$ , $i = 1,..N$

Comment: Okay, I'm starting to get it, thanks. Now, if the expected value is over the $N$ sampled pairs $(x_i, y_i)$, then is $\hat{f}$ _truly_ a random variable in this context?

Comment: $\hat{f}(x; \omega)$ is an estimate on y, governed by the input data $x$ and a parameterization $\omega$. These variables are also drawn from a distribution $x$ ~ $X$ and $\omega$ ~ $\Omega$, plus additional things like learning algorithm stochasticity, model choice, etc. Therefore the output $f(x; \omega)$ will also have a distribution, therefore an expected value, bias and variance, in respect to an unknown 'true model' $f(x) = y $

Comment: @hirschme, sorry just to clarify, you have $\hat{f}$ written at the top there, and then $f$ written twice afterwards. Are you saying $f$ is a random variable, or $\hat{f}$ is, or both?

Comment: Sorry the second f should be $\hat{f}$. $\hat{f}(x)$ is our estimate of $f(x)$, which is a perfect model defined as $f(x) = y + \epsilon$. We never see $f(x)$ (only indirectly through y), we only deal with $\hat{f}(x)$ which can be seen as a random variable, and use $f(x)$ to compute bias and variance of our model $\hat{f}(x)$. They are both random variables, as $f(x) = y +\epsilon$ you can see it has stochasticity included through the stochastic noise term $\epsilon$ ~ $N(0,\sigma^2)$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86350/discussion-between-user3002473-and-hirschme).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have a measure of the perfomance of our model $f(x)$ on approximating the map $x \rightarrow y$, we define an error (cost) function that measures the distance between our target $y$ and our estimate $\hat{y} = f(x)$ which we desire to minimize. An usual error term choice is the mean squared error MSE, which is the squared (direction insensitive) residuals, averaged over all sampled data pairs $(x_i,y_i), i=1,...,N$. This average is our approximation of the expected value of this residuals and can be written $\mathbb{E}[(y - f(x))^2]$.

The values of $f(x)$ will follow a distribution, governed by the inputs $x_i$, and other factors such as model choice, parameterization and so on. We can compare the performance of this model against a 'perfect' model $y = f(x) + \epsilon$. Having defined this perfect model $f(x)$, we call our model an estimate of this, thus now called $\hat{f}(x)$ and used in you equations.